# My function does not enter the for loop and I dont know why

Tags: c++, function, for-loop

```
void dibuja(int lineas, char caracter){
int i=0,j=0;
cout<<lineas<<caracter;
for(i = 1; i == lineas; i++){

     for(j=i; j<=lineas; j++){
       cout<<caracter;
     }

   cout<<endl;
 }
}
```

So I have this code and when I try to run it compiler returns no errors but the function dont enter in the loop. It prints lineas and caracter but dont the triangle that its supossed to do.

Comment: `c` or `c++` make up your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for` loop is nothing more than a glorified `while` loop.

A loop such as

```
for (init_expression; loop_condition; iterator_expression)
    loop_statement;
```

is equal to

```
{
    init_expression;

    while (loop_condition)
    {
        loop_statement;
        iterator_expression;
    }
}
```

If you see it like that, it might be easier to understand that your `for` loop loops while `i == lineas` is `true`. Which with your initialization expression will only be if `lineas` is equal to `0`, and then it will loop only once because the next iteration (when `i` is equal to `1`) the condition will no longer be true.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you mean

```
for(i = 1; i != lineas; i++){
```

instead of

```
for(i = 1; i == lineas; i++){
```

Answer (score 1):

The for loop take as second "argument" the loop condition... Like "loop while..." and because you have `i == lineas` it never go inside the loop.

You should use `i <= lineas` or `i != lineas`

Answer (score 1):

You probable meant to write `for(i = 1; i != lineas; i++)` or `for(i = 1; i < lineas; i++)` in your for loop.

You can think of the condition as "perform the instructions in `for` loop, as long as the condition is true. As `i` does not equal `lineas` at the beginning, the loop does not get executed at all.